# How to search in files for string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How can I check the availability of a string in all files with grep?

I try to search a string in a file and I only need one output.

The problem: I have many strings in an array and each string must searched individually.

I'd like to know in which file a string exists.

Thank you for all answers!

Comment: Which files are you trying to grep? Can you cut your code down to only the relevant part?

Comment: What do you mean "check with grep"? Check for what? Grep for what?

Comment: I try to check the packages of the availability in /tmp/packages-puppy-*.

Comment: You need to make it clear exactly what you are trying to do and what problem you are having. Instead of posting all of your code, reduce it to only the part related to your question.

Comment: @linuscl : before posting to an english-speaking forum, please make sure that also the code that you post is in english, and not in german.

Comment: it is hard to tell anything, because we don't know what contains the `/tmp/packages-puppy-*`, what contains the `/tmp/packages-install` and so. Therefore isn't possible to tell, how your script will react. If you asking such questinons, you **should** provide example data to have an replicable test case... Please, read [ask]. Anyway, you can also use `bash -x scriptname.sh` (or `set -x` inside of your script) to see, how your script works.

Comment: @ francesco stablum : I change my script! :)

Comment: Here you can find all files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1log90jw3jgj67m/AAAf30RamnQ6cCQvzf_1HcLAa?dl=0                       I hope you can help me.

Comment: Summary: I'd like to know in which file a string exists.

Comment: So you have a string in a variable and you would like to show which file also contains the string?

Comment: Exactly! You've understood it!

Comment: Does my answer work then, or do you want to do something different? You really need to [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25460449/edit) to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: I have **many** files to search in an array, not only one. That is the problem!

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you have any problems with it, you can comment on it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string in a variable:

```
search="string"
```

You can use `grep -l` to list all of the files that contain the string:

```
grep -lFr "$search" /path/to/search
```

The `-F` switch means that the search pattern is a fixed string, not a regular expression. The `-r` switch means that grep does a recursive search of all files in the path.

If you have an array of strings to search for:

```
search=( string1 string2 )
```

You can use a loop like this:

```
for s in "${search[@]}"; do 
    echo "first file containing $s"
    grep -lFr "$s" . | head -n 1
done
```

The use of `head` means that only the first file that contains the string is printed.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I will try to explain. First, it was not clear what you were asking. You posted a long script but nobody knew where the problem was. Now you have removed all of the script, it looks like you haven't tried anything. A good question explains clearly what you are trying to do, shows what you have tried and makes it clear what the problem is. Maybe you should try to edit this question so that it contains a short example of what you were trying to do and explain exactly what the problem is. Then people might upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is mainly because in your (now deleted) script do you uses

```
grep -n -w "$name" /tmp/packages-puppy-*
                        ^ - lowercase "p"
```

and in the Dropbox you have some filenames with uppercase "P" and some with lowercase "p".